# Removing Watermark from a PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

I had been used the first code create a water mark and removed and it work perfect

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string workingFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string startFile = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "StartFile.pdf");
        string watermarkedFile = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "Watermarked.pdf");
        string unwatermarkedFile = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "Un-watermarked.pdf");
        string watermarkText = "This is a test";

        //SECTION 1
        //Create a 5 page PDF, nothing special here
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(startFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
            using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER)) {
                using (PdfWriter witier = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
                    doc.Open();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                        doc.NewPage();
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph(String.Format("This is page {0}", i)));
                    }

                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        //SECTION 2
        //Create our watermark on a separate layer. The only different here is that we are adding the watermark to a PdfLayer which is an OCG or Optional Content Group
        PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(startFile);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(watermarkedFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader1, fs)) {
                int pageCount1 = reader1.NumberOfPages;
                //Create a new layer
                PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("WatermarkLayer", stamper.Writer);
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount1; i++) {
                    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = reader1.GetPageSize(i);
                    //Get the ContentByte object
                    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);
                    //Tell the CB that the next commands should be "bound" to this new layer
                    cb.BeginLayer(layer);
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 50);
                    PdfGState gState = new PdfGState();
                    gState.FillOpacity = 0.25f;
                    cb.SetGState(gState);
                    cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                    cb.BeginText();
                    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, watermarkText, rect.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2, 45f);
                    cb.EndText();
                    //"Close" the layer
                    cb.EndLayer();
                }
            }
        }

        //SECTION 3
        //Remove the layer created above
        //First we bind a reader to the watermarked file, then strip out a bunch of things, and finally use a simple stamper to write out the edited reader
        PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(watermarkedFile);

        //NOTE, This will destroy all layers in the document, only use if you don't have additional layers
        //Remove the OCG group completely from the document.
        //reader2.Catalog.Remove(PdfName.OCPROPERTIES);

        //Clean up the reader, optional
        reader2.RemoveUnusedObjects();

        //Placeholder variables
        PRStream stream;
        String content;
        PdfDictionary page;
        PdfArray contentarray;

        //Get the page count
        int pageCount2 = reader2.NumberOfPages;
        //Loop through each page
        for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount2; i++) {
            //Get the page
            page = reader2.GetPageN(i);
            //Get the raw content
            contentarray = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.CONTENTS);
            if (contentarray != null) {
                //Loop through content
                for (int j = 0; j < contentarray.Size; j++) {
                    //Get the raw byte stream
                    stream = (PRStream)contentarray.GetAsStream(j);
                    //Convert to a string. NOTE, you might need a different encoding here
                    content = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream));
                    //Look for the OCG token in the stream as well as our watermarked text
                    if (content.IndexOf("/OC") >= 0 && content.IndexOf(watermarkText) >= 0) {
                        //Remove it by giving it zero length and zero data
                        stream.Put(PdfName.LENGTH, new PdfNumber(0));
                        stream.SetData(new byte[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Write the content out
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(unwatermarkedFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader2, fs)) {

            }
        }
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

but when I used digital sign some time when a I tried to remove the watermark some page lost the information , them I'm would like to used the PdfLayerRemover and I change to C# but when I made this

```
 PdfDictionary ocProps = _reader.Catalog.GetAsDict(PdfName.OCPROPERTIES);
```

I had been used the first code create a water mark and removed and it work perfect but when I used digital sign some time when a I tried to remove the watermark some page lost the information , them I'm would like to used the PdfLayerRemover and I change to C# but when I made this

PdfDictionary ocProps = _reader.Catalog.GetAsDict(PdfName.OCPROPERTIES);

always get null value and the pdf has the watermark??? please if can help me and the pdf has ocpproperties because when I use this works but it remove additional information . but the way Itextshap version 5.5.2.0

```
if (content.IndexOf("/OC") >= 0 && content.IndexOf(watermarkText) >= 0) {
                    //Remove it by giving it zero length and zero data
                    stream.Put(PdfName.LENGTH, new PdfNumber(0));
                    stream.SetData(new byte[0]);

                }
```

Comment: Unfortunately you do not tell us details of the signing process.

Comment: I have a Crystal report  document I generate a pdf them I put a watermark, the document is  sign in a table, using acrobat and the document was saved, this document later is upload to the system  and the watermark is removed and I put other watermak, the problem is when the first watermark is removed, but, no in all document I had this problem (the  document had 50 page) and not always

Comment: Can you provide a sample PDF for which things go wrong, in each stage of the process? You say the issue occurs only sometimes. Thus, there may be a reason in the PDFs in question.